# Numpy mask by rows

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2D array:

```
matrix =np.array([[95,90,-1,55],[100,90,-1,80],[0,90,85,100]])
```

I try to choose 2 random rows, and ignore -1.

I tried:

```
random_ints = np.random.choice(len(matrix), size=2, replace=False)
students = matrix[random_ints, :]
ignored = students[students != -1]
```

but the ignored var reshaped to 1D array for example:

```
[95,90,55,100,90,80]
```

I want the ignored saved 2D for example:

```
[[95,90,55],[100,90,80]]
```

How can do that?

Comment: What happens when one row has two -1s and the other only has one?

Comment: The output should be  [[95,90],[100]]

Comment: That's not a valid numpy array. That's why masks can't preserve shape.

Answer (score 0):

If you had **equal** number of elements to be left (*!= -1*) in
each row, you could run:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: row[row != -1], 1, students)
```

To check this variant, set `random_ints = np.array([0,1])`, select just
the above rows to *students* and run the above code.

But if the number of these element is **different**, *Numpy* will
raise exception:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (4)
```

The reason is that (in this case) some rows have **4** elements to be
left, whereas other - only **3**.

Unfortunately, *Numpy* does not support "jagged" arrays (with different
number of elements in each row).

You can get **something like** you wanted, but as a **nested list**
(not a *Numpy* array):

```
result = []
for row in students:
    result.append(row[row != -1].tolist())
```

The result (for rows *2* and *1*) is:

```
[[0, 90, 85, 100], [100, 90, 80]]
```